# Does Shutterstock have a minimum resolution, or pixel density?

Tags: resolution, dpi, stock-photography

Similar to [Noise reduction, upload to shutterstock declined](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/122295/noise-reduction-upload-to-shutterstock-declined)

I uploaded some photos to Shutterstock, which got through to review. They were all shot on an Olympus OMD E-10 Mark III, as JPEG's. All had the same resolution of 350 dpi, 24-bit and were 4608x3456. All 5 were rejected citing

> Focus: The main subject is out of focus or is not in focus due to camera shake, motion blur, overuse of noise reduction, or technical limitations of the equipment used (e.g. autofocus searching, camera sensor quality, etc).

> Noise / Artifacts: Content contains noise, film grain, compression artifacts, pixelation, and/or posterization that detracts from the main subject.

Is it as simple as uploading RAW images, instead? Or are they rejecting due to the technical capacity of my camera?

Answer (score 1):

They will not accept raw images, and they are not rejecting the images due to the technical capabilities of your camera; an OMD E10 III is certainly capable of meeting their minimum requirements.

They are rejecting them for the way your camera was/is set to record the images. Some of that is quite possibly due to the in-camera jpeg processing settings (picture profile, etc). And some of it is quite likely user error/technique.

BTW, they were not 350DPI, a jpeg (digital image) doesn't have a fixed DPI; and jpegs are 8bit...

Comment: I pulled that detail from the exif. I guess I've still got a lot to learn.

Comment: well... 8-bit (per RGB channel), 24-bit... in this instance, it's two ways of saying the same thing

Comment: Steven, do you have first hand experience with SS, because IMHO this expression "They are rejecting them for the way your camera was/is set" do not have much sense in SS.

Comment: @osullic, yes 8bit/channel can also be said as 14bit color; but that is pretty unusual in terms of describing a jpeg... i.e. most image et=ditors (PS, Preview, Gimp, etc, etc) describe it as 8bit color and jpegs as 8bit files.

Comment: @RomeoNinov, tyes, I have some experience with stock agencies including SS. In this case they stated images were rejected for lack of detail/sharpness (focus/motion blur/etc) which would be settings/technique. And also due to artifacts (noise reduction/compression/etc) which would also likely be camera settings (picture style) as they were recorded as jpegs in camera.

Comment: @StevenKersting, seems like your experience is not quite deep (with SS). Few years ago before they change the pricing, images review was on another level. And if you see "noise" you really have noise. No they "optimize the expenses" and currently this is only excuse.

Comment: @RomeoNinov, I quick stock agencies years ago...

Answer (score 0):

Here are the [requirements](https://support.submit.shutterstock.com/s/article/What-are-the-technical-requirements-for-images?language=en_US) for the images you should upload in Shutterstock.

- JPEG or TIFF
- sRGB
- 4MP minimum
- 50 MB for photos, 100 MB for EPS. If you upload via FTPS, you can upload JPEGs up to 50 MB, EPS files up to 100 MB, and TIFFs up to 4 GB in size.

About rejections: in last year or so SS implement low quality AI (or hire low quality personal) and usually such "excuses" have nothing to do with the reality.

Comment: I feel that's the case here. My images exceeded those requests.

Comment: @spikey_richie, those (about the quality) are not only my personal observations. When SS had a forum many people complain about unreasonable rejections.

Comment: I do agree that their reasons are "canned"/automated (select the closest one) and may not make complete sense in the photographers view.

Comment: @StevenKersting, in 95% of the cases they do not make any sense at all. My portfolio there is ~8k images...